# Github Personal Authentication Token not working for Github API

Tags: javascript, axios, github-api

I m trying to request https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:react+state:open&sort=created&order=desc&per_page=100&page=1 using my personal authentication token but it always returns 422 status. The way i m using the token is on headers like this:

```js
{
  headers: {
    authorization: `token ${myToken}`
  }
}`
```

I dont know if i m doing something wrong but i supose this code should be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, after reading "[How to send the authorization header using Axios](https://flaviocopes.com/axios-send-authorization-header/)", try:

```js
axios.get('https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=react+state:open&sort=created&order=desc&per_page=100&page=1', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `token ${access_token}`
  }
})
```

Try also to generate your token, considering its [format has recently changed](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-31-authentication-token-format-updates-are-generally-available/) (March 2021)

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67392661/github-personal-authentication-token-not-working-for-github-api/67396537?noredirect=1#comment119136560_67396537) by the [OP Gabriel Mazurco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15541901/gabriel-mazurco) below, no more `repo:`.

Comment: Thanks by the way not only the token format, github also changed endpoint params like: ':repo', ':user', ... now requires a oauth authentication, so i just removed the old parameters from the request

Comment: @GabrielMazurco Good to know: what does the new request look like?

Comment: the same, but without the repo: that i writed on request like this: https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=react+state:open&sort=created&order=desc&per_page=100&page=1

Comment: @GabrielMazurco OK. I have included your comment and the HTTPS URL in the answer for more visibility. Thank you for the feedback.